# how to get form posted value in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am developing a form plugin in wordpress, What i want is when any one submit form on my website my plugin can get all form values and can save it in database.

Here is my code.

I set form action. 
http://www.mywebsite.com?action=myform&redirect_url=thank-you

`add_action('init', array(&$this, 'get_form_parameters'));// init function`

```
 

    //to get form values
    function get_form_parameters() {
                global $_POST;
                global $wp_query;

                if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['action'])) {
                    print $wp_query->query_vars['action'];
                    exit();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables like this

```
 function get_form_parameters($name, $email, $pass) {
            global $_POST;
            global $wp_query;

// you can use direct these variables in function like echo $name, $email, $pass

            if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['action'])) {
                print $wp_query->query_vars['action'];
                exit();
            }
```

and use function like this where you want :

```
get_form_parameters($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']);
```

if you have any doubt then please let me know

Comment: Is it work in wordpress? I use the same but its not work in wordpress plugin.